# Go back from ess-remote state in emacs

Tags: emacs, ess

Sorry for any duplicates, but I am lacking the correct words to google the answer myself.

I am using ess with emacs to run R in a terminal in emacs, kind of like:

1. Start emacs
2. M-x term, start bash
3. Start R (interactive mode)
4. M-x ess-remote, select R as language.

When I quit R, I want to turn off the ess-state and use the normal "term" state.

I am using GNU Emacs 23.2.1 and ess v. 13.05.

Answer (score 1):

No easy way. Unless you use screen, the preferred way to use ESS with remotes is through tramp. See the official [docs](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers).

Comment: I cannot ssh into the remote machine, should I still use tramp? And can you explain what you mean by using 'screen'?

Comment: @MrGumble Tramp supports a variety of protocols. I personally use it only with ssh for remote access and have no experience with anything  else. You should also update your emacs and ESS. ESS 13.9-1 sorted a lot of remote-specific stuff.